# Change Number of Values in CCK Filefield/Upload

Tags: entities, files

Using hook_form_alter(), how would I change the default of 1-10 then Unlimited, to 1-24 then Unlimited?  CCK Only gives 1-10 as options before going to Unlimited and I need to have 1-24.  I know this is possible using hook_form_alter() but I do not know the syntax of how to write that.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'content_field_edit_form') {
    $form['field']['multiple']['#options'] = array(1 => t('Unlimited'), 0 => 1) + drupal_map_assoc(range(2, 24));
  }
}
```